# Animating TableView Instead of Plain Reloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to animate the reloading of a table view. Currently, I download the array of table view items and if the user reloads the table view manually, it downloads into a separate array, compares the current to the newly downloaded, and if they are different, it reloads the table view with the newly downloaded array. Is there an easy way to, somehow, compare the arrays and insert/delete rows (animated, of course) accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Apple's Table View Programming Guide to be very useful for this question:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: I know, but how would I compare the arrays and find out which rows to insert and delete?

Comment: It might not be the fastest, but you could loop through the first array and find the ones that are not there in the second, and those are the ones to delete, so you put those in a "to delete" array. Then do the same for the 2nd array, and those are the one to put in a "to add" array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arrays, you would need to deal with figuring out inserted/deleted rows. If you are dealing with a larget set of data, then you should consider using Core Data with `NSFetchedResultsController`. See [documentation for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) for getting inserted/deleted rows.